# Gorhom/Bottom-Sheet: making a Floating Component place at the top of Bottom Sheet in React Native

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I need some help.
I want to make a component like a floating component always placed at the top of the BottomSheet (when the BottomSheet moving, it moving too).

I've tried the BackDrop, Handler but not as I expected

Gorhom/bottom-sheet website: [Website Borhom/Bottom-Sheet](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/)

Here is the image:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried the BackDropComponet, HandlerComponent but that is not as I expected.

Comment: Hii please have a look into example -> bare 
File name Weather.tsx may be that might help you :)

https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/blob/master/example/bare/src/components/weather/Weather.tsx

Answer (score 0):

just add a normal view with translateY style based on sheet move event